# beego, redefined page not found, 404 page is not show html, why?

Tags: html, go, http-status-code-404, beego

I redefined the `page_not_found` on router.go,

```
func page_not_found(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles(beego.ViewsPath + "/404.html")
    data := make(map[string]interface{})

    t.Execute(rw, data)
}
```

and in `init` function used

`beego.Errorhandler("404", page_not_found)`

when i called 404 by used `this.Abort("404")` in controller, the 404 page was not show html, it showed the page html text, liked this

[image: html text/plain]

Comment: The normal error.go do mention a content-type (https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/master/middleware/error.go). Does your 404 html page do the same?

Comment: i changed my 404 html to a normal html, then it worked.

Comment: do you mean you change something in the code source of your 404.html page?

Comment: Yes, like the below answer.

Comment: Excellent. An actual html page, then. +1

Answer (score 1):

because i wrote 404 html liked this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/a.css">
<div class="html404">
    <div class="title">404</div>
        <div class="link">
            <div><a href="/">回首页</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it caused the question. when i changed the html to

```
<html>

<head>
     <title>Aiysea 404 Page</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/a.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="html404">
        <div class="title">404</div>
            <div class="link">
                <div><a href="/">回首页</a>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

then it gone well.